# match a regex in a formatted alphanumeric string

Tags: python, regex

Why

```
re.match(r"^[0-9]+minutes?$", "10 minute")
```

is not matching ?

I used also :

```
re.match(r"\d+minutes?$", "10 minute")
```

Comment: You forgot the space between `+` and `minutes`

Comment: Also `minutes` vs `minute`

Comment: @Cyber he makes the s optional so no problem.

Comment: give a space in ur regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget to add the pattern (`\s`) to match the  in-between space.

```
>>> re.match(r"\d+\sminutes?$", "10 minute")
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 9), match='10 minute'>
```

since `re.match` tries to match the input string from the begining, you don't need to put starting anchor `^`.

Answer (score 0):

a simple  `^[0-9]+ minutes?$`

Will do it.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/yG7zB9/12